# How to build in different environments with SCons?

Tags: build, environment-variables, scons

I just discovered SCons, a great build tool.

I need to build my project in multiple environments, i.e. with different library paths and include paths depending on the machine.

Since `SConstruct` has all of Python available, I can imagine various ways to accomplish this. One possibility would be to have a single `SConstruct` script and instantiate multiple `Environment` objects.

```
envFoo = Environment()
envFoo.Append(CPPPATH = [...])

envBar = Environment()
envBar.Append(CPPPATH = [...])
```

Then select one of these `Environment` objects somehow, possibly with a command line parameter to `scons`.

A question for experienced scons users:  Is this the way to go? What is the most convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would definitely work, and would probably be a good solution for simpler situations. I have a more complex situation where I actually create an EnvironmentFactory using Python classes, something like this:

```
env = EnvironmentFactory.createEnv(cmdLineArgs)
```

Another useful SCons tool would be to "automatically" populate the Environment from the command line options using the ParseFlags(), ParseConfig(), and MergeFlags() as described in [this chapter](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c1818.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
envSelect = ARGUMENTS.get('env', "default")

if envSelect == "default":
    env = Environment()
elif envSelect == "env2":
    env = Environment(whatever you want to do here)
elif envSelect == "env3":
    env = Environment(whatever you want to do here)
else:
    env = Environment(whatever you want to do here)
```

With the ARGUMENTS.get you specify a default when you just run the command `scons`
or else you you do `scons env=env2` hope this answers your question

EDIT :  here's a snippet from a project I'm working on where I want to determine the os when scons runs

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import subprocess
#Find the host Operating System
platform = sys.platform

if platform != "win32":
    env = Environment()
else:
    #Specify to compile in 32-bit mode for Visual Studio
    #This is needed as Qt libraries on Windows for Visual
    #Studio are 32-bit only
    env = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = 'x86')

#Get Qt directory as scons argument or use default setting
if platform != "win32":
    qtDir = ARGUMENTS.get('qt', '/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.4/')
else:
    qtDir = ARGUMENTS.get('qt', 'C:\\Qt\\4.8.4\\')
```